# Java unit test for different input data

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I need to test some api. For example I have multiple @Test methods in the class to test my functionality, before init I connect to some url of my service, and use it.

If I have my service at multiple urls(different server environments), how can I Test this functionality for different service urls?

**Flow:**

1. Init conncetion by url
2. Run all Tests
3. Init conncetion by another url
4. Run all Tests(the same)
5. ...

when was only one host I do like this:

```
public class TestAPI{
    @org.junit.Before
    public void init() {
      service = new Service("www.test.com");
    }
    @org.junit.Test
    public void testA(){
      service.CallA(); 
    }
    @org.junit.Test
    public void testB(){
     service.CallB(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Happen to me sometime, and them I found this awesome idea called Parameterized Test, for instance:
http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/
in this way you can all the same tests couple of time with different argument.

Answer (score 9):

there are prameterized tests: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/ and http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/writing-a-parameterized-junit-test/.

alternatively, you can make your test case abstract and subclass it with each subclass setting up the url.