# Many GET request on REST assured - JAVA

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, http, rest-assured

I have list strings with some urls:

- `localhost:80/my/first/url`,
- `localhost:80/my/second/url`

there can be 2, 5 or more urls. I must check which adres respond me with error 500.

```
@Test()  //bad test
public void checkErrorStatusForURLs() {
    for(String url : urlList()) {
        given().when().get(url)
               .then().statusCode(CoreMatchers.not(500));
    }
}
```

I dont want write tests for each url. Can i do it on one test? How to do it correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java unit test for different input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028188/java-unit-test-for-different-input-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Junit 4's parameterized tests as described here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests

Something along the lines of this may work for you:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {

@Parameters
public static Iterable<? extends Object> urls() {
    return Arrays.asList("localhost:80/my/first/url", "localhost:80/my/second/url" );
}

@Parameter 
public /* NOT private */ String url;

@Test
public void checkErrorStatusForURLs() {
        given().when().get(url)
               .then().statusCode(CoreMatchers.not(500));
 ...
}
}
```

Comment: it's working on 4.12 version junit, Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract statusCode and then check what evere condition you want like this:

```
for(String url : urlList()) {
    int statusCode = given().when().get(url).then().extract().statusCode();
    if(500 == statusCode) {
        //add it to a list??
    }
}
```